# Implement WebSocket-Client "gabbo"

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to implement BOSE Soundtouch API using WebSockets, but don't quite know how.

from https://developer.bose.com/guides/bose-soundtouch-api/working-websockets

> When creating a client WebSocket connection, your application will need to connect to port 8080 on the product you want to receive notifications from. Be sure to specify the protocol as "gabbo" - otherwise the connection will not succeed.

and then

> Once a WebSocket is created, your application will begin receiving events as the product sends them. Try playing some music on the product -- you should see events quickly start to roll in.

How can I do this in Delphi 10.3? Is there a component for it? Can Indy do this?

Comment: take a look at this python library : https://github.com/CharlesBlonde/libsoundtouch, it wouldn't be too hard to convert this to delphi

Comment: You CAN do it in Indy, if you are willing to implement the WebSocket protocol manually, or use a 3rd party implementation (there are a few floating around). There is currently [no WebSocket client component available in Indy](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/201).

Comment: You can't ask us about finding a component here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.